# Insert one to many record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I'm facing a problem regarding inserts with the Entity Framework.

My application has the following two entities:

- Memo
- Employee

A Memo can be linked with multiple Employees.
A Employee can be linked with multiple Memos.

Which means a many to many relation.
I read a few articles explaining me that a junction table should be created, which I think is obvious.

The articles learned me to let Entity Framework automatically create a junction table for me. So I did this the following way:

**Memo**

```
public Guid MemoId { get; set; }
public String Message { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

**Employee**

```
public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Memo> Memos { get; set; }
```

When updating my database using the Package Manager Console, a junction table has been created in the database. I did this using following line:
`update-database -force -verbose`

I have a view for creating a new Memo.
It is possible to select a list of Employees here and add them to the Memo.
However filling this junction table isn't going as planned. I think it has something to do with the setup of my repositories. I created a MemoRepository and a EmployeeRepository.

My controller handling the Memo create is as follow:
**MemoController**

```
public class MemoController : Controller
{
    private IMemoRepository _memoRepository;
    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public MemoController(IMemoRepository memoRepository, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        _memoRepository = memoRepository;
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Create() {
        //Initializes MemoCreateViewModel here
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MemoCreateViewModel model) {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Create");

        Guid employeeId;
        List<Guid> employeeIds = new List<Guid>();
        foreach (var id in model.SelectedEmployeeIds) {
            if (!Guid.TryParse(id, out employeeId)) {
                continue;
            }
            employeeIds.Add(employeeId);
        }
        var employees = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeesByIds(employeeIds);
        model.Memo.Employees = employees.ToList<Employee>();
        _memoRepository.SaveMemo(model.Memo);

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
}
```

**MemoRepository**

```
public class EFMemoRepository : IMemoRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context;

    public EFMemoRepository(EFDbContext _context) {
        context = _context;
    }

    public IQueriable<Memo> Memos {
        return context.Memos;
    }

    public void SaveMemo(Memo memo) {
        if(memo.MemoId == Guid.Empty) {
            memo.MemoId = Guid.NewGuid();
            context.Memos.Add(memo); //error 1 here 
        } else {
            Memo dbEntry = context.Memos.Find(memo.MemoId);
            if(dbEntry != null) {
                dbEntry.Message = memo.Message;
                dbEntry.Employees = memo.Employees;
            }
        }
    context.SaveChanges(); //error 2 here
    }
}
```

Error 1 I get when inserting:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

Error 2 I get when updating:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

How can I resolve this, I read topics about people saying it has something to do with using different contexts, others say it has something to do with `Attach()`, but I have no clue how to resolve this within my application.

Please, tell me if you require more information.

Note: I left out some code, to make it easier to read. Code can be added if requested of course.

Comment: Why are you using this approach? Isn't it possible that you create the database first with the required junction tables and foreign keys then create the model from it. That way it is much easier. I personally prefer this way because changing the database design from the code is not always the best approach to from database perspective. Unless it is a legacy system or a business requirement.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen My colleges prefer this way and I don't really mind using code first. Tevertheless it should be possible using the Code first way..

Comment: Yes you are right, but when you are going into a direction that will not give you any leverage but hitting your head to the wall, and if you know there exist alternative(not workarounds) ways, than that is not so productive, is it?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Future problems will not occur when I have a solution for this one. I can continue same way for other One to Many inserts / updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the 1st error because you are adding the Memo object that is passed in to the context. But the employee object that was added to the memo object inside the controller was retrieved using another dbContext. To fix that you must share the db context between the two operations OR you must explicitly attach the Employee object to the current context.

Option 1:
CONTROLLER CODE

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MemoCreateViewModel model) {
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Create");

    Guid employeeId;
    List<Guid> employeeIds = new List<Guid>();
    foreach (var id in model.SelectedEmployeeIds) {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(id, out employeeId)) {
            continue;
        }
        employeeIds.Add(employeeId);
    }
    EFDbContext dbContext = new EFDbContext();//Note
    var employees = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeesByIds(dbContext, employeeIds);//Note the extra parameter
    model.Memo.Employees = employees.ToList<Employee>();
    _memoRepository.SaveMemo(dbContext,model.Memo);//Note the extra parameter

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

EFMemoRepository CLASS CODE:

```
public void SaveMemo(EFDbContext dbContext, Memo memo) 
{
    if(memo.MemoId == Guid.Empty) 
    {
        memo.MemoId = Guid.NewGuid();
        context.Memos.Add(memo); //error 1 here 
    } else 
    {
        Memo dbEntry = dbContext.Memos.Find(memo.MemoId);
        if(dbEntry != null) 
        {
            dbEntry.Message = memo.Message;
            for (int i = 0; i < dbEntry.Employees.Count; i++)/*Please note that if lazy loading is not True then this reference must explicitly be loaded*/
            {
              dbEntry.Employees.Remove(dbEntry.Employees.First());
            }
            foreach (var item in memo.Employees)
            {
                dbEntry.Employees.Add(item);
            }
           context.Entry(dbEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;                
        }
    }
    dbContext.SaveChanges(); //error 2 here
}
```

OR

OPTION 2:

```
public void SaveMemo(Memo memo) 
{
    if(memo.MemoId == Guid.Empty) 
    {
        memo.MemoId = Guid.NewGuid();
        context.Memos.Add(memo); //error 1 here 
    } else 
    {
        Memo dbEntry = context.Memos.Find(memo.MemoId);
        if(dbEntry != null) 
        {
            dbEntry.Message = memo.Message;
            for (int i = 0; i < dbEntry.Employees.Count; i++)/*Please note that if lazy loading is not True then this reference must explicitly be loaded*/
            {
               dbEntry.Employees.Remove(dbEntry.Employees.First());
            }
            foreach (var item in memo.Employees)
            {
                dbEntry.Employees.Add(item);
            }   
            context.Entry(dbEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;              
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges(); //error 2 here
}
```

Personally I would go with option 1 or something along those lines.

Shout if anything is unclear

Comment: The insert works:) But the update is not adding records to the junction table called: MemoEmployees. What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes. To update using the same method you will have to delete all previous employee relationships and add them again. In that way you will delete the no longer valid relationships and add the newly created relationships

Comment: I updated my answer to do this. Please have a look and see if that works for you

Comment: I tried, it does grab the correct Employee to delete at `dbEntry.Employees.First()`. And it does insert the correct Employees at `dbEntry.Employees.Add(item);` but it doesn't change the Junction table records in the database, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The fact that you are adding and removing Employees from the Memo's navigation property to Employees should update the bridge/junction table only and not any other tables. Is this then deleting and inserting in the Employees table?

Comment: They are not inserted or deleted in Memo, Employee and MemoEmplyees. What I think is odd.

Comment: This seems very odd. The only other thing I can think of is to add this inside the else block 'context..Entry(dbEntyr).State = EntityState.Modified;'. I have update the code accordingly

Comment: Also make sure the 'context.Memos.Find(memo.MemoId);' call actually finds a records.